# Create datarame from elements from two other dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

The following code works perfectly. It creates a dataframe by comparing elements from two other dataframes and filtering them.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'i': [40, 40, 40, 41, 41],
                    'j': [140, 140, 140, 141, 142],
                    'k' : [140, 141, 142, 141, 142],
                    'avg': [33, 31, 30, 33, 29]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'i': [10, 40, 10, 41, 21, 11],
                    'j': [110, 140, 110, 141, 122, 111],
                    'k' : [110, 141, 142, 141, 122, 111],
                    'avg': [31, 30, 40, 31, 25, 29]})

offset = abs(df1.loc[0,'i'] - df2.loc[0,'i'])

df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["i_ref", "j_ref", "k_ref", "i_sim", "j_sim", "k_sim", "avg_ref", "avg_sim", "deviation [%]"])
for row1 in df1.itertuples():
    for row2 in df2.itertuples():
        if (abs(row1.i - row2.i) == offset) & (abs(row1.j - row2.j) == offset) & (abs(row1.k - row2.k) == offset):
            df3 = df3.append({
            "i_ref": row1.i,
            "j_ref": row1.j,
            "k_ref": row1.k,
            "i_sim": row2.i,
            "j_sim": row2.j,
            "k_sim": row2.k,
            "avg_ref": row1.avg,
            "avg_sim" : row2.avg,
            "deviation [%]" : abs(row1.avg-row2.avg)*100/row1.avg
            }, ignore_index=True)
```

However in my actual case where df1 and df2 have 1 million entry each (read from a csv file), the calculation takes forever.

My question: is there a more efficient way to get to the same result?

Comment: One thing that might help your efficiency is to compare the conditions one at a time; if it doesn't meet the first condition then move on instead of trying all three each iteration. I tested on one combination of your inputs (merged df1 and df2) and found `[abs(df4[f'{item}_x']-df4[f'{item}_y'])==offset for item in ['i']]` runs in `487 µs` and `[abs(df4[f'{item}_x']-df4[f'{item}_y'])==offset for item in ['i','j','k']]` runs in `1.34 ms`